# How is a for loop implemented in a Makefile recipe

Tags: shell, makefile

Although the below script, is intended find a makefile in the sub directory level of 1 and make them recursively, I'm not able to find any success with it.

```
for file in `find $(pwd)/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f -name 'Makefile'`; do\
    make --directory=$(dirname $file);\
done
```

What might be the problem here?

Comment: I don't think for loop is the best solution for your problem. Try to find solution from this page: http://locklessinc.com/articles/makefile_tricks/ or one of the many others in the Internet.

Comment: The unescaped dollar sign will get evaluated by Make before the loop runs; so `$(dirname $file)` will produce `ile` (unless you happen to have a Makefile variable `f` with an interesting value).

Comment: I see,"for file in `find $(pwd)/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f -name 'Makefile'`; do\
    make --directory=$(dirname $$file);\
done" gets converted to  "for file in `find / -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f -name 'Makefile'`; do\      
 make --directory=;\
done". Replacing $(pwd)/ with . yields the same result. What's that I can do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this recipe you do not intend `$(pwd)`, `$(dirname ...)` and `$file` to be expanded by `make`,
but they are are, because you have not escaped `$`. (Strictly, you do not intend the `$f` in `$file` to be expanded by `make`). Re-write as:

```
for file in `find $$(pwd)/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f -name 'Makefile'`; do\
    make --directory=$$(dirname $$file);\
done
```

**Later**

> Is there a better and simple way of making sub modules of a project?

Yes. The canonical way would be like:

```
# Identify the sub-directories some way, not necessarily like this:
SUBDIRS := $(dir $(shell find $$(pwd)/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f -name 'Makefile'))

.PHONY: $(SUBDIRS)

all: $(SUBDIRS)
# Maybe some recipe...

$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

Comment: Rather, "for file in `find $$(pwd)/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f -name 'Makefile'`; do\
    make --directory=$(dirname $$file);\
done" didn't work.

Comment: To keep the script clean, I'm now using "SUBMAKES := $(shell find $(pwd)/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f -name 'Makefile')" followed by "$(foreach var,$(SUBMAKES), make --directory=$(dirname $$var);)". Dumping the makefile database with -p option, I see the result as "for file in ``; do\
 make --directory=;\
done"

Comment: @NandanBharadwaj My mistake, I forgot to escape `$(dirname ..`). Corrected.

Comment: So the answer explains that $$ are needed, one for make environment and other for the shell environment i.e running inside the make environment right.The loop worked indeed. Thanks a lot Mike.

Comment: Do please let me know, is there a better and simple way of making sub modules of a project?